# Create multiple pagination using codeigniter with the same index

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I need to paginate my search results using codeigniter in the same page..
the result was divided by 2 part book  and news..so I need multiple pagination
and the result have the same index `http://xxx/xxx/advancedsearch/searchbasic/index/2?search=`
I have paginate but it doesn't right..
because when I click the 2nd links [1 **2** 3 4]
the news also change like that..
Can anyone help me?

I have heard about ajax pagination but it seems hard..

Answer (score 0):

You will have but two options here: clone the CodeIgniter library or use ajax. The ajax option would be easy by using jQuery.get() and some controller actions specifically coded for ajax, usually just a JSON string response back to jQuery, but that is some work! The cloning idea is a great one actually.
Your library would be like this:

class Test_Controller extends CI_Controller {

```
public function page(){

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $paginationA = clone($this->pagination);
    $paginationA->initialize(array('uri_segment' => 3));

    $paginationB = clone($this->pagination);
    $paginationB->initialize(array('uri_segment' => 4));

}
```

}

Comment: the problem is I'm using query string.. is it possible?